# How I can check condition base on the value of css custom property in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a css custom property contain the value of theme color: `var(--themeColor)`.

And I want to check the value of theme color whenever it is `white` then I can change the value of `background-color` to another value.

For example:

```
.btn {
    background-color: var(--themeColor) == "white" ? "red" : var(--themeColor);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a css variable value using this js snippet:

```js
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--themeColor').trim();
```

So then with styled-components you can achieve this ternary operator test to get the color:

```css
.btn {
    background-color: ${getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--themeColor').trim() === "white" ? "red" : "var(--themeColor)"};
}
```